# regex best practice?

Tags: regex, database, content-management-system

Today I got an email from my boss saying to change the regex in our java script code that goes onto our client's website from

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]
```

to

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]
```

because one of our clients were complaining that it wasn't regex best practices and it's causing problems with their CMS and their DB.

Looking at those two regexes, It appears to me they match the exact same thing.

the . and the - are swapped at the end, but that shouldn't make a difference. Should it?

Am I missing something?

The developer from our client's company is really adamant about us changing it.

Can someone shed some light?

Thanks!

Comment: @Mike: Almost everything you said is wrong. You seem to be missing the fact that \ is the escape character.

Comment: you are correct, for some reason i thought that slash was escaped.  hah

Comment: actually then \- and \. get two different things completely.

Comment: @Mike: '-' and '.' respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no functional difference.

If anything is having issues with that regex, then it is a non-standard/buggy implementation. I recommend finding out exactly what the problem is.

While I see no reason to change it, I see no reason *not* to change it, so do what you wish.

Tip: I'm guessing the regex is written wrong. If I know what it is supposed to mean, I would write it:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+[_\.\-]?
```

Comment: I agree with you that there's no reason not to change it. I will go on and change it for them. I was just curious why they were saying it was a "broken format." I've emailed them back and asked them for specifics. If I get an answer I'll put up an update.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `-` in a character group, it goes last otherwise it denotes a range of characters, like `A-Z`. If you're escaping it, like you are, then it can be anywhere.

It's possible the CMS or other code they use un-escapes the regex, so in this case it will throw errors if the `-` isn't the last character in the group. I would say that having as few escaped characters in a regular expression as possible makes it easier to read, but that's from a personal perspective.

Comment: Note that not all regular expression syntaxes support the backslash escape inside a character class, in which case both forms actually include backslash as a legal character.  (But are equivalent to each other since the one with the hyphen has a backslash on either side, and `[\-\]` is the same as `[\]`.)